# How to solve $A \frac{dy}{dx} + By = f(x)$ boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a linear first order o.d.e. so I really feel that I should be able to solve this but would appreciate help.
$A$ and $B$ are constants. $f(x)$ is a unit pulse function, which I believe is equivalent to a unit step-on (Heaviside) function at some value $x=a$ and a step-off at $x=b$.
The boundary value are: $y(x=\infty) = y(x=-\infty) = 0$

I have solved this using Laplace transforms but to be honest I'm not sure I trust my solution.

For a=0 and b=1000, I have obtained:
$y=y(0).e^{-Bx} + \frac{1}{AB}(u_0(1-e^{-Bx})-u_{1000}(1-e^{-B(x-1000}))$

And for y(0), I have looked at x tends to infinity, and have obtained
$y(0)=\frac{1-e^{1000B}}{AB}$

As I check my workings again, any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Thanks Michael for cleaning up the title. Still figuring out how to drive this thing ...

Comment: Just realised I should be using Fourier not Laplace transforms